# How to automate deployment of ngnix configuration on Amazon AWS?

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, symfony5

i have a created project using symfony 5.
For hosting website i am using amazon AWS.
Amazon AWS instance is using nginx.
Everytime i deploy code using Elastic beanstalk i have to add following lines to the etc/nginx/nginx.conf file

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

if i don't add following configuration and don't restart nginx server then only page of my website is visible . Whenever i try to open another page of website excepts homepage i get following error :

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.18.0
```

How can i automate deployment of the ngnix configuration whenever i upload code using elasticbeanstalk ?

Comment: What platform are you using? It should be listed in your environment dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify your nginx configuration, you should modify your Configuration Files by extending ElasticBeanstalk as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)

I will assume you are using Amazon Linux 2, if not the ElasticBeanstalk is working completely differently as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.container.html).

Elastic Beanstalk (using Amazon Linux 2) will automatically look for a `.platform` directory at the root of your zip file.

By adding `.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/php-custom.conf` with the following content, you should be good to go (assuming you are using the default configuration). Note that you could overwrite the `nginx.conf` by adding this file `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf` to your project, but since what you want to do is fairly simple, I would only add a file that will be automatically loaded by nginx.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

So your project tree should look something like this.

```
project root
├── .platform
│   └── nginx
│       └── conf.d
│           └── elasticbeanstalk
│               └── php-custom.conf
└── your project files
```